# Classloader mystery in Tomcat + Spring environment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, static, classloader

I have two java static methods for class A:

```
private static String value;
public static void setValue(String str) {
    value = str;
}
public static String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

sounds simple. I call A.setValue("someValue"), then in some other classes which loaded by spring application context, I call A.getValue(), I am getting null back; while at the same time, in the original place, the A.getValue() still returns "someValue".

So it seems to me there are two instances of the same java class in the tomcat JVM. Is there some way to make sure there is only one instance for one java class?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the jar files located? Which ones are in WEB-INF/lib and in Tomcat's shared folder?

Comment: it's all in WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you actually don't have a singleton here and are seeing the class A loaded by two different class loaders? One solution in this case would be to have the Spring bean created (not as prototype) and injected into the two places you are using it - so the framework manages the life cycle of the singleton. If this is still a problem you might want to consider the design of the above, specifically with regards to concurrent access.

Comment: I thought whether it is singleton only affect how many instances of the object. I am using static method, not sure why it is affected. But anyway, I will try to put singleton there and see what happens, thank you.

Comment: I actually think you're right here, but I find this problem interesting. My current theory, which is probably illustrated by your title, is that Spring is creating the class on its local loader vs the other place you are trying to update it. That's the only reason the above can happen right? Is it not possible to Spring manage both?

Comment: just realized that the spring entries are coming from lib/jar files, I could not change.

Comment: RE: Jim:  Yes, that's what I thought too, I am trying to find a way to use "flat" class loader, which load all the WEB-INF/lib/jar files and class files in one class loader. Not sure whether it is doable, and what's the setting if it is.